# Sorting in O(n) without any temp variable

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I need to design an algorithm which will sort an array which contains numbers -1,0,1 only, without using any temp variable or array and by using only swapping I have come up with the following method I'm not sure if it is O(n).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10

int main()
{
    int array[MAXSIZE];
    int i, j, num = 8, temp;

    int list[] = {-1,0,-1,0,1,1,0,1};

    int size = sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {

        if (list[i] < list[i - 1]) {
            list[i] = list[i] + list[i - 1];
            list[i - 1] = list[i] - list[i - 1];
            list[i] = list[i] - list[i - 1];
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted array is...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is _not_ bubble sorting, since bubble sorting needs a comparison against all succeeding elements and thus is quadratic in runtime.

Comment: Maybe you just count the number of -1s, 0s and 1. Then reproduce an array with the correct number of each starting at -1 first..

Comment: I dont need any specific algorithm I just need to verify complexity of the algorithm I wrote

Comment: [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your algorithm has been stated correctly by @RSahu, you are resetting the counter to 0 which means you can do as much as `1+2+...+n` iterations.

Here is a small example exhibiting linear time to process the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<int,10> A{-1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1};

    int i=0,j=0, k=9;
    while(j!=k) {
        if(A[j] == 0) {
            ++j;
        }
        else if(A[j] == -1) {
            swap(A[i], A[j]);
            ++i; ++j;
        }
        else {
            swap(A[j], A[k]);
            --k;
        }
    }

    for(auto ai : A)
        cout << ai << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

You can see it live [there](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82c7cee92159c026).

How does it work ? We maintain three counters `i`, `j` and `k` with the invariants that:

- all items in the range: `[0, i)` are `-1`
- all items in the range: `[i, j)` are `0`
- all items in the range: `(k, n-1)` are `+1`

Where `[` means an inclusive bound, and `)` or `(` means an exclusive bound.

**Initially**

`i=j=0` and 'k=n-1`. The invariants are respected.

**First case**

```
if(A[j] == 0) {
    ++j;
}
```

The value of `A[j]` is 0, so we can increment `j` and the invariants still hold.

**Second case**

```
else if(A[j] == -1) {
    swap(A[i], A[j]);
    ++i; ++j;
}
```

As `i` is an exclusive bound, we are adding a `-1` to the previous range of `-1` and the increment of `i` is needed. If the range `[i, j)` was not empty, a `0` has been copied to position `j` and we must increment `j`. If the range was empty, then we had `i==j`, and as we increment `i` we must also increment `j` to keep the invariant. We can conclude that the invariants still hold after this step.

**Third case**

```
else {
    swap(A[j], A[k]);
    --k;
}
```

`A[j]` is `0` we can swap it with the value at `A[k]` and decrement `k` and the invariants will hold.

**Termination and correctness**

The final point is proving the program will terminate. Each step either:
 - increment `j`
 - decrement `k`
So the distance between `j` and `k` will decrease by 1 every step.

The distance between `j` and `k` is initially `n-1`, and decreases by one every step. So there will be at most `n-1` steps. Each step does one swap. There will be at most `n-1` swaps.

At the end of the program the invariants will hold:

- from `0` to `i` excluded, all `-1`
- from `i` to `j==k` excluded, all `0`
- from `j==k` to `n-1` excluded, all `+1`

Comment: Thank you @fjardon

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm is definitely not O(n).
You are setting `i` to `0` when you do a swap. At worst, it is O(n^2).

Comment: is it possible to improve it to O(n)?

Comment: it is definitely possible to do it in O(n), you can check out how quicksort works, it can give you a general idea

Comment: @JKLM, I don't know of any sorting algorithm that can perform better than O(N.log(N)). If there is any, I will be glad to educate myself.

Comment: the trick is, with elements only being of 3 different values, it's more of a "partition" than a "sort"

Comment: radix sort maybe?

Comment: @Afshin the main limitation is I need to use only swapping I'm not sure about counting sort

Comment: @RSahu what about using binary search to insert an item at specific place in a linked list? While the last item has a cost of `log(n)`, the item before that has a cost of `log(n-1)` and so on, for a total cost lower than `O(n.log(n))`. Or am I misunderstanding the big O notation?